# Controller can't find requested when calling a standard action in Yii 1.x

Tags: php, yii

While trying to execute a standard Yii action, I'm getting an exception, that `HotelController` cannot find the requested view `hotellist`.

My controller code is (important parts):

```
class HotelController extends Controller
{   
    public $defaultAction = 'HotelList';

    public function actionHotelList()
    {
        $model = new HotelRev;  

        $this->render('hotellist', array('model'=>$model));
    }   
}
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: hotellist.php is in inside of hotel folder. yah?

Comment: yes hotellist is inside a views\hotel

Comment: if permission is good for that folder/file then post exact error message.

Comment: throw new CException(Yii::t('yii','{controller} cannot find the requested view "{view}".',

Comment: if you are on a linux based system, see for case sensitivity. If that's not the issue, make sure you did not make a typing error. That's all i can help.

Comment: will you show your directory structure of `view` directory and also which os you are implementing.

Comment: Thank you all,i get know what the actually problem 'hotellist' file not behave like a "PHP" file...lolzzz i  edited that file and save as a hotellist.php Now it's worked perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem - the first letter of the directory created in protected/views cannot start with a capital letter (on Linux systems anyway).

if **views/Hotel** than make them **views/hotel**